# Xcode 4 file complete path

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.1

If I have any file open in Xcode and I would like to know the complete path to the file, how do I do that in Xcode 4? In Xcode 3 I could hover over the file name and get a tooltip with the complete path. I could also right-click a file name at the very top and get a pop-up window with the complete path. This is all gone in Xcode 4.

The annoyance is that when using the Xcode 4 search, it doesn't even show the complete path of the file in the results?!

The only solution I have currently found is to open the save as dialog and get the path from there! That definitely can't be the solution. What am I missing?

Comment: One solution is 'ctrl'+click the filename and choose 'Show in finder'. At least that should be far better than your 'save as' dialog.

Comment: The filename is listed in 2 places as fas as I can see. In the editor window itself right after the navigation arrows (Go back and forward).  It also listed at the top of Xcode beside the open project name. Ctrl+click (on either) didn't reveal any 'Show in finder' option for me. Could you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For files that are not part of the project you can use the File menu's Show in Finder option.

**Update:** Xcode 4.2 restored the ability to right-click or command-click on the file's name in the title bar to get a drop-down with the full path.

Comment: This is by far the best solution till now. Pity there is no way to see the full path on-the-fly without having to execute a command.

Comment: +1 thanks, and @Tamer: agree, at the very least hover over file tab should pop up a "tooltip" with the file full path.

Comment: Update seems to be no longer valid in XCode 7.0, however File > Show in Finder option works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Show the file inspector utility (normally at the right hand side of the main window on my setup , to do that click the rightmost button of the "View" buttons menu). Click on your file in the navigator and the inspector will refresh with the information. Full path is disclosed and there is a button to open a new Finder window with the enclosing folder.

Comment: Though using the utility window is helpful, its still not what I'm looking for. Since it depends on the fact that the file is part of your project (in which case usually u already know where it is). However sometimes/usually, I search in folders that aren't part of my project completely. Opening a file from the search results, will show no information about it in the utilities window. I was just thinking there must be an option to always see the currently opened (in the text editor) file's full path immediately. Regardless if its part of your project or not.